# SteamVR Short Distance Grab

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, virtual-reality, steamvr

I am making a VR game using the SteamVR plugin. In this plugin, they make it so you can grab things when your hand is on it. However I would like to be able to pick things up from the floor when standing up, or a lease a little farther away. A good game that shows this ability is Rec Room. The tutorial I followed was this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5C6zr4Q5AlA&ab_channel=Valem If anyone has the answer to this it would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If you go into the hand objects and change the hover radius it will increase the grabbing size.